# Call webservice from ms sql server 2017

Tags: c#, sql

I have sql table  where one of column contains  code  of territorial division of the country. The code is retrived from public webservice when user add the record  to databse using  my program writted in C# and WPF. Now I need to create a sql  view to display data in datagrid, where the code is convert back to the name using the same web service which is used before to get the code. What is the best way to achieve this ? I don't want to store the name in database,because the name could change,but the code always remain the same.

Comment: If you want to fetch the data in real time each time a client queries the view, then you will have to create a CLR function that uses e.g. `WebRequest`. It may or [may not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752357/sql-server-2008-how-crash-safe-is-a-clr-stored-procedure-that-loads-unmanaged-l#comment60595563_36493550) be a good idea.

Comment: Get your C# app to convert the code back to the name when it reads the data. It can cache the responses.

Comment: Roger Lipscombe this is good idea  but how to  "join" data from sql with data from webservice when binding ? For example  I have  columns: first name,last name and  id of city. So how to create a source for datagrid where the id of each record is converted "dynamically"  to names using webservice ?